# What are non-commercial sources of road network other than OSM

Tags: data, network

I want to get the graph (Road Network) of **Area of interest**:

Longitude / Latitude

```
`Left/Bottom = 
-93.28587,44.9674` 
and `Right/Top=
-93.25351,44.9855`
```

Minneapolis, MN

Searching for a non-commercial source - aside from [Open Street Map](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) (OSM) - of a road dataset containing routing and network cost attributes.

Comment: This is pretty vague... can you be more specific?

Comment: I just want the graph of a region containing the highways and roads inside that region. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Even with that clarifying comment, user31820, it's hard to tell what you're looking for.  Is this question about obtaining a dataset or about a procedure to extract features from a dataset?  Or something else?  And what precisely do you mean by "graph"?  (This term has *many* quite different technical meanings in GIS and related fields, ranging from types of visual representations of data to abstract mathematical assemblies of vertices and edges.)

Comment: Yeah obtaining a dataset defining the graph basically a list of edges their corresponding nodes and cost

Comment: In GIS terminology, it appears you are asking "where are there sources of vector datasets of highways and roads which have explicit topology and travel cost attributes?" One way to narrow this still-broad question would be to specify whether commercial sources are of interest, to indicate what scale (or precision) is needed, and how current the information needs to be.

Comment: No I don't intend to use commercial sources. It's fine that it not 100% accurate. I just need this graph to run some experiments

Comment: It would depend on your area of interest and scale as to exact answers

Comment: BTW node and graph are not common GIS terms in regards to data aquistion. Unless you dig past where your getting them from and get into the "data" the source contains. As stated previously ,"Vector" dataset with routing/network cost attributes would be more clarifying. That is if I  understand your question. Then you can begin to specify the region. which will let someone help with a possible link to what you are looking for.

Comment: Rather than try to clarify your question by responding with a little extra information each time someone tries to help, my recommendation would be to overhaul your original question to assist us to understand what you are hoping to find out.

Comment: @BradNesom I want the data for this region leftbottom = -93.28587,44.9674 and righttop=-93.25351,44.9855

Comment: yes I need the "Vector" dataset with routing/network

Comment: usually you create your own data for routing (edges, nodes, costs) from data

Answer (score 4):

I have found that searching numerous US State GIS agencies has yielded road information for download in .shp format free of charge.

Answer (score 2):

I Googled "[minnesota gis data](https://www.google.com/search?q=minnesota%20gis%20data&rls=com.microsoft:en-us&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&startIndex=&startPage=1)", which took me to the [Minnesota Geographic Data Clearinghose](http://www.mngeo.state.mn.us/chouse/).

From there I selected [Data](http://www.mngeo.state.mn.us/chouse/data.html), then under Data Catalogs, I selected [Mn/DOT](http://www.dot.state.mn.us/maps/index.html) (i.e. Department of Transportation).

At the next webspace, under the **GIS maps** heading (right side, half-way down), I selected "[MnDOT basemap data files](http://www.dot.state.mn.us/maps/gisbase/html/datafiles.html)".

Here, needing some additional reference info, I followed [the **Statewide Data** link](http://www.dot.state.mn.us/maps/gisbase/html/statewide.html) and  downloaded the [MN State Boundary](http://www.dot.state.mn.us/maps/gisbase/datafiles/statewide/state.zip), [MN County Boundaries](http://www.dot.state.mn.us/maps/gisbase/datafiles/statewide/county.zip), [Trunk Highway System (?)](http://www.dot.state.mn.us/maps/gisbase/datafiles/statewide/StateTH.zip), and [Municipal Boundaries](http://www.dot.state.mn.us/maps/gisbase/datafiles/statewide/muni.zip).

Next, I created a shapefile of your region of interest (RIO) using the Well Known Text (WKT) expression for your bounding box coordinates. The goal was to determine which county your ROI fell within (because the MnDOT high definition road data is split apart by county). That said, the WKT expression for your RIO is this:

```
POLYGON ((-93.28587 44.9674, -93.28587 44.9855, -93.25351 44.9855, -93.25351 44.9674, -93.28587 44.9674))
```

Finally, as you see in this screenshot, I was able to determine that your ROI fell in Hennepin County, Minnesota:

- Dark Green = State Background
- Light Green = Hennepin County
- Orange Boundary = Minneapolis (visualized for convenience)
- **Yellow Boundary = your ROI**.

[image: ArcMap view with Hennepin County, Minneapolis Boundary, and custom ROI]

Once I knew I needed the Hennepin County MnDOT data, I returned to the [MnDOT basemap data files site mentioned earlier](http://www.dot.state.mn.us/maps/gisbase/html/datafiles.html), [selected County Based](http://www.dot.state.mn.us/maps/gisbase/html/county_graphic.html), then [chose Hennepin County](http://www.dot.state.mn.us/maps/gisbase/html/hennepin.html).

Do this, and you'll find a lonesome dataset just waiting for you. Or in other words, [*this exact file*](http://www.dot.state.mn.us/maps/gisbase/datafiles/county/hennepin.zip).

Having said all this, all I really did was follow the advice of @wstewart1958 and apply some GIS basics (admittedly the WKT stuff was probably over the top, but all you needed was a 4-point polygon defining your ROI to visualize the placement).