# Graph of a specific area of USA

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2pgrouting, geography, osm2po

I am trying to get the network graph of a specific reason of USA. I have got a couple of options. One of them is using osm2po tool to extract the nodes and edge table from the osm map of a specific reason.

I tried with this one and I could get the graph in the database table. But I think that there is property called geom_way, that defines the intermediate nodes of each edge. I mean suppose I have an edge like this

```
edgeid = 1;
source_node = 1;
target_node = 152
source_lat_lon = -93.27368,44.98204
dest_lat_lon = -93.27254,44.98124
geom_way = 0105000020E6100000010000000102000000040000006F641
```

Then if I decode the geom_way it will be the coordinates of the intermediate nodes between source_lat_lon and dest_lat_lon.

Well I need to run the shortest path algorithm on this graph. So I was wondering if it could create some issues.

Also I was wondering if there is any alternative tool or way to get the graph of a specific area of USA except osm2po.

Comment: Any reason you can't edit your very similar [other question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27477/how-to-get-the-node-and-edge-graph-of-a-region)?